# Sum won't increment in visual basics 2013

Tags: vb.net

I'm having this codes at all forms so I could have a sum of score in my quiz. But when the score form shows up in the end, it shows 0 and is more likely not incrementing when i have a wright or wrong answer. I'm sorry its my first time to make in VB basics. Wish someone could help.

```
Public Class Form2

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles NextButton1.Click
        If Option2.Checked Then
            Score.ScoreRight.Text = Score.ScoreRight.Text + 1
            Dim Form2 As New Form3
            Form3.Show()
            Me.Hide()
        Else
            Score.ScoreWrong.Text = Score.ScoreWrong.Text + 1
            Dim Form2 As New Form3
            Form3.Show()
            Me.Hide()
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: what is `Score`?  A form?  A Class? A textbox?  Also turn on Option Strict

Comment: If you use [Option Strict On](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx), it might point out enough problems for you to fix your code. P.S. It is Visual Basic, with capital letters and no plural s.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that Score is a form and that Score.Scoreright and score.scorewrong are textboxes in that form

try this maybe

```
Public class Score
  Dim withevents Form2instance as new Form2
  Dim withevents Form3instance as new Form3

  Dim rightAnsweres as integer = 0
  Dim wronganswers as integer = 0

  Public sub Updateresults()
    Scoreright.text = rightansweres
    ScoreWrong.text = wronganswers
  End Sub

  Public sub Form2Instance_QuestionAnswered()Handles Form2Instance.QuestionAnswered
  if Form2Instance.AnsweredCorrectly = true then
    rightansweres = rightansweres+1
  else
    wronganswers = wronganswers + 1
  end if
  Form2instance.Hide
  UpdateResults()
  Form3instance.show
  end sub
end class
```

Now in your form2 and form3 classes you need an event and you need to raise the event when the question is answered.

```
Public Class Form2
  Public event QuestionAnswered()
  Property AnsweredCorrectly as integer = False
  Sub RunThisAfterYouHaveIndicatedWhetherOrNotTheAnswerWasCorrect()
    RaiseEvent QuestionAnswered()
  End Sub
end class
```

Now to explain
You are trying to call a routine inside of a general class type and expecting the results to be updated inside of an active instance of that class. Or so it seems.

You have to have some kind of reference to the instance of the class that you're trying to update.

In this example, The class you're trying to update has a reference to the forms that it needs information from. It receives the information by waiting for the form to raise an event and then handles it's business.

Comment: I will also recommend to you a very good/inexpensive website that will teach you so much through video tutor. LearnVB.net is absolutely amazing and teaches you so much that you didn't know you needed to learn.

Answer (score 0):

Is Option2 a checkbox? If so, i think you need to use the .checkstatus property of the checkbox instead of .checked

```
If Option2.checkedstate = checkedstate.checked then
```